# H2O : NullPointerException error while building ensemble model using deep learning grid

Tags: java, r, deep-learning, h2o

I am trying to build a stacked ensemble model to predict merchant churn using R (version 3.3.3) and deep learning in h2o (version 3.10.5.1). The response variable is binary. At the moment I am trying run the code to build a stacked ensemble model using the top 5 models developed by the grid search. However, when the code is run, I get the java.lang.NullPointerException error with the following output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hex.StackedEnsembleModel.checkAndInheritModelProperties(StackedEnsembleModel.java:265)
    at hex.ensemble.StackedEnsemble$StackedEnsembleDriver.computeImpl(StackedEnsemble.java:115)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:173)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1349)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Below is the code that I've used to do the hyper-parameter grid search and build the ensemble model:

```
hyper_params <- list(
                  activation=c("Rectifier","Tanh","Maxout","RectifierWithDropout","TanhWithDropout","MaxoutWithDropout"),
                  hidden=list(c(50,50),c(30,30,30),c(32,32,32,32,32),c(64,64,64,64,64),c(100,100,100,100,100)),
                  input_dropout_ratio=seq(0,0.2,0.05),
                  l1=seq(0,1e-4,1e-6),
                  l2=seq(0,1e-4,1e-6),
                  rho = c(0.9,0.95,0.99,0.999),
                  epsilon=c(1e-10,1e-09,1e-08,1e-07,1e-06,1e-05,1e-04)
                )

search_criteria <- list(
                      strategy = "RandomDiscrete",
                      max_runtime_secs = 3600,
                      max_models = 100,
                      seed=1234,
                      stopping_metric="misclassification",      
                      stopping_tolerance=0.01,                  
                      stopping_rounds=5
                    )

dl_ensemble_grid <- h2o.grid(
                          hyper_params = hyper_params,
                          search_criteria = search_criteria,
                          algorithm="deeplearning",
                          grid_id = "final_grid_ensemble_dl",
                          x=predictors,
                          y=response,
                          training_frame = h2o.rbind(train, valid, test),
                          nfolds=5,
                          fold_assignment="Modulo",
                          keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                          keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment = TRUE,
                          epochs=12,
                          max_runtime_secs = 3600,
                          stopping_metric="misclassification",
                          stopping_tolerance=0.01,        
                          stopping_rounds=5,
                          seed = 1234,
                          max_w2=10
                        )           

DLsortedGridEnsemble_logloss <- h2o.getGrid("final_grid_ensemble_dl",sort_by="logloss",decreasing=FALSE)

ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = predictors, 
                            y = response, 
                            training_frame = h2o.rbind(train,valid,test), 
                            base_models = list(                                                   
                                                DLsortedGridEnsemble_logloss@model_ids[[1]],
                                                DLsortedGridEnsemble_logloss@model_ids[[2]],
                                                DLsortedGridEnsemble_logloss@model_ids[[3]],
                                                DLsortedGridEnsemble_logloss@model_ids[[4]],
                                                DLsortedGridEnsemble_logloss@model_ids[[5]],
                                              )
```

Note: what I have realised so far is that h2o.stackedEnsemble function works when there's only one base model and it gives the Java error as soon as there's two or more base models.

I would really appreciate if I could get some feedback as to how this could be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error refers to a line of the [StackedEnsembleModel.java code](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/rel-vajda/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/StackedEnsembleModel.java#L265) that checks that the `training_frame` in the base models and the `training_frame` in `h2o.stackedEnsemble()` have the same checksum. I think the problem is caused because you dynamically created the training frame, rather than defining it explicitly (even though that *should* work since it's the same data in the end).  So, rather than setting `training_frame = h2o.rbind(train, valid, test)` in the grid and ensemble functions, set the following at the top of your code:

```
df <- h2o.rbind(train, valid, test)
```

And then set `training_frame = df` in the grid and ensemble functions.

As a side note, you may get better DL models if you use a validation frame (for early stopping), rather than using all your data for the training frame.  Also, if you want to use all the models in your grid (might lead to better performance, but not always), you can set `base_models = DLsortedGridEnsemble_logloss@model_ids` in the `h2o.stackedEnsemble()` function.

Comment: Also found out that when I passed four values (c(0,0.05,0.1,0.2) to the 'input_dropout_ratio' during grid search, that caused the ensemble function to fail. But when I passed c(0,0.05) and c(0.1,0.2) on two separate runs, then the ensemble function worked on both occasions.

Comment: @Erin  Your answer here is really helpful.  I was using Pythron and had passed something like df_all[idx_train, :] to each level_0 learner as well as the ensemble.  And I was getting exactly the same error.  Just defining df_train = df_all[idx_train, :] upfront, fixed it.  Thanks!!